# Not correct regular-expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to split some lines, with letters and number, but I cannot come up with the appropiate regular expression.

The format of the lines is something like unit = value+unit, some examples:

```
width = 3.45cm
height = 2m
width = 2mm
height = 6.67m
```

And I would like to get a separate output for each name, value and unit, this is what I have done:

```
line = infoData.readline()
names = []
values = []
units = []
while line:

    if "=" in line:
        names.append(line[0:line.index("=")])
        m = re.search('\d+', line[line.index("="):len(line)])
        values.append(int(m.group()))
        m = re.search('\D+[^=\n\.]', line[line.index("="):len(line)])
        units.append(m.group())
        line = infoData.readline()

    else:
        line = infoData.readline()
```

The only thing that I'm getting in a desired way its the names....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overcomplicating matters a little. I'd use:

```
data = []

for line in infoData:
    if '=' not in line:
        continue
    name, value = line.split('=')
    value, unit = re.search('([\d.]+)(\w+)', value).groups()

    data.append({'name': name.strip(), 'value': float(value), 'unit': unit})
```

For your sample data that gives you a list of dictionaries with:

```
[{'name': 'width', 'unit': 'cm', 'value': 3.45},
 {'name': 'height', 'unit': 'm', 'value': 2.0},
 {'name': 'width', 'unit': 'mm', 'value': 2.0},
 {'name': 'height', 'unit': 'm', 'value': 6.67}]
```

instead of 3 separate lists.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, nice short and good answer!!, that answers another question that I had about how to do that when I have, for example 67 or when I have 67.23.

Comment: @user2919052: ah, yes, that was a mistake on my part where the regular expression only matched integers. Corrected.

Comment: Great again, using your first expression I already came up with something like that myself, but still THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

```
data = ["width = 3.45cm","height = 2m","width = 2mm","height = 6.67m","nope"]

import re
pattern = re.compile("(\w+)\s*=\s*([\d.]+)\s*(\w+)")
print [pattern.search(items).groups() for items in data if pattern.search(items)]
# [('width', '3.45', 'cm'), ('height', '2', 'm'), ('width', '2', 'mm'),
#  ('height', '6.67', 'm')]
```

RegEx Demo:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ZxiAKuizC1TsSVrB)

**Edit:** If you are looking for a way to get a dictionary out of a RegEx, you can do that like this

```
import re
patt = re.compile("(?P<name>\w+)\s*=\s*(?P<value>[\d.]+)\s*(?P<unit>\w+)")
print [patt.search(items).groupdict() for items in data if patt.search(items)]
```

**Output**

```
[{'name': 'width', 'unit': 'cm', 'value': '3.45'},
 {'name': 'height', 'unit': 'm', 'value': '2'},
 {'name': 'width', 'unit': 'mm', 'value': '2'},
 {'name': 'height', 'unit': 'm', 'value': '6.67'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for a nice RegEx explanation + example Thefourtheye!!

Comment: Why does your output have the `value` and `unit` keys swapped? :-P